# Change of variables of a random variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics, education

I'm looking for a way to perform the change of variable of a random variable. In particular, I've a random variable $X$ with probability density function:

$$
f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
a \, e^X \quad &\text{if } x \leq 1 \\
3 \, (1 - a \, e) \, x^{-4} \quad &\text{if } x > 1
\end{cases}
$$

where $a \in [0, \, e^{-1}]$. The goal is to get the probability density function of $Y = X^3$. How can I do it in Mathematica?

The result should be:

[image]

---

EDIT: error in $0 < y < 1$: the exponent sign of the exponential $e$ is + not -.

Comment: First, you should take a tutorial of Algebraic statistics...

Comment: Hello @Rom38 I know how to solve it manually. Btw the above one is the solution of my professor (he is a professor of Scuola Normale Superiore).

Comment: ©wolfies I think it is you who made a mistake. `Integrate[Piecewise[{{a E^x, x <= 1}}, 
  3 (1 - a E) x^-4], {x, -∞, ∞}]` gives 1 for every value of $a$.

Comment: @Roman: And the integrand is non-negative if `a>=0,a<=1/E`.

Comment: Oopps - yes - I misplaced a bracket

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the probability distribution for $X$:

```
fx[a_, x_] = Piecewise[{{a E^x, x <= 1}}, 3 (1 - a E) x^-4];
px[a_] = ProbabilityDistribution[fx[a, x], {x, -∞, ∞}];
```

Find the PDF of $Y=X^3$:

```
py[a_] = TransformedDistribution[x^3, Distributed[x, px[a]]];
fy[a_, y_] = PDF[py[a], y]
```

$$
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1-e a}{y^2} & y>1 \\
 \frac{a e^{\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3-y\&,1\right]}}{3 \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3-y\&,1\right]^2} & y<1 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$$

Check numerically for a specific value, for example $a=0.1$:

```
With[{a = 0.1},
  X = RandomVariate[px[a], 10^4];
  Y = X^3;
  GraphicsRow@{
    Show[
      Histogram[X, {1/30}, "PDF"],
      Plot[fx[a, x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], 
      PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 1}}], 
    Show[
      Histogram[Y, {1/30}, "PDF"], 
      Plot[fy[a, y], {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], 
      PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Roman thank you very much for your answer. Can you explain me the meaning of the symbols # and & please?

Comment: This is not so simple. If we put `a = 1/2/E;`, then  we obtain `Piecewise[{{1/(2*y^2), y > 1}, 
  {((-1)^(2/3)*E^(-1 + (-1)^(2/3)*y^(1/3)))/(6*y^(2/3)), 
   y < 1}}, Indeterminate]` which is far away of the required result and incorrect. Likely a bug in `TransformedDistribution`.

Comment: @wolfies: Your words do not correspond to reality in view of `Integrate[
 Piecewise[{{a*Exp[x], x <= 1}, {3*(1 - a*E)*x^-4, 
    x > 1}}], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> a >= 0 && a <= 1/E]` resulting in `1`. It is clear the integrand is non-negative for such `a`s.

Comment: I wonder the upvotes for the wrong answer.

Comment: @user64494 maybe you are alone in thinking that the answer is wrong.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi pleas look up [pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#17469).

Comment: @Roman:  Your `fy[a_, y_]` differs from the formula given in the question and does not reflect the behavior near $y=0$. I tried to simplify the PDF when $a=\frac 1 {2e}$ for $y\in(-\infty,0]$ and for $y\in (0,1)$ and something went wrongly (explanation, but not justification). Sorry for the "wrong answer".

Comment: @user64494 Yes the OP has a typo in the formula for $0<y<1$ which should be $\frac{a}{3}y^{-2/3}e^{y^{1/3}}$ (sign mistake in the exponent).

Comment: @Roman: In any case your`fy[a_, y_]` does not explicitly reflect the behavior near $y=0$.

Comment: BTW, the output of `Series[fy[1/10, y], {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> y < 0]` i.e. $\frac{(-1)^{2/3}}{30 y^{2/3}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{-1}}{30 \sqrt[3]{y}}+\frac{1}{60}+\frac{1}{180} (-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{y}-\frac{1}{720} \sqrt[3]{-1} y^{2/3}+\frac{y}{3600}+O\left(y^{4/3}\right)]$ is complex-valued: `N[(-1)^(2/3)]` produces `-0.5 + 0.866025 I`.

Comment: @Roman thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an extended comment based on @Roman's answer.

That answer using `Root` objects takes care of the cases where $y<0$ and $0<y<1$ just with the restriction $y<1$.  But if you want to have the cases where $y<0$ and $0<y<1$ made explicit *and* have the function look in a more standard way, then you'll need to do some of the work "by hand" using the `ToRadicals` function.

```
pdfyLessThan0 = FullSimplify[(a E^Root[-y + #1^3 &, 1])/(3 Root[-y + #1^3 &, 1]^2) //
  ToRadicals, Assumptions -> y < 0]
```

[image: pdf for y<0]

```
pdfyBetween0and1 = FullSimplify[(a E^Root[-y + #1^3 &, 1])/(3 Root[-y + #1^3 &, 1]^2), 
  Assumptions -> 0 < y < 1]
```

[image: pdf for 0<y<1]

```
pdfyGreaterThan1 = FullSimplify[fy[a, y], Assumptions -> y > 1]
```

[image: pdf for y>1]

```
pdfy = Piecewise[{{pdfyLessThan0, y < 0}, {pdfyBetween0and1, 0 < y < 1},
  {pdfyGreaterThan1, y > 1}}, Indeterminate]
```

[image: pdf of y=x^3]

And, of course, you need the restriction that $0<a\leq \frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: +1. Nice. I did something similar, but it went wrongly. (I used `ToRadicals` with assumptions.)

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT

```
Clear["Global`*"]

distx3[a_] = ProbabilityDistribution[
   Piecewise[{{a E^x, x <= 1}}, 3 (1 - a E) x^-4], {x, -∞, ∞}];
```

Plotting the `PDF` of the this distribution

```
Plot3D[PDF[distx3[a], x],
 {x, -3, 5}, {a, -4, 4},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, a, PDF})]
```

[image]

Since a `PDF` cannot be negative, the distribution must be redefined to exclude the regions where the function is negative.

```
distx2[a_] = ProbabilityDistribution[
   Piecewise[{{a E^x, x <= 1 && a > 0},
     {3 (1 - a E) x^-4, x > 1 && a < 0}}], {x, -∞, ∞}];
```

However, this is not normalized:

```
Assuming[a > 0,
 Integrate[PDF[distx2[a] // Simplify, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]

(* a E *)

Assuming[a < 0,
 Integrate[PDF[distx2[a] // Simplify, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]

(* 1 - a E *)
```

Normalizing the distribution gives

```
distx[a_] = ProbabilityDistribution[
   Piecewise[{{E^(x - 1), x <= 1 && a > 0},
     {3 x^-4, x > 1 && a < 0}}], {x, -∞, ∞}];

Plot3D[PDF[distx[a], x],
 {x, -3, 5}, {a, -4, 4},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, a, PDF})]
```

[image]

```
disty[a_] = TransformedDistribution[x^3, Distributed[x, distx[a]]];

PDF[disty[a], y]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@PDF[disty[a], y],
 {y, -3, 5}, {a, -4, 4},
 PlotRange -> {0, 2},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 MaxRecursion -> 4,
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {y, a, PDF})]
```

[image]